# SQLite CASE Between two tables

Tags: sqlite

SQLite CASE Between two tables
I have 2 tables "topics" and "sub"

TABLE TOPICS :

```
+------------+-------------+
| id_topic   | topic_name  |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | books       |
| 2          | food        |
| 3          | movies      |
| 4          | weather     |
| 5          | travel      |
| 6          | pets        |
+------------+-------------+
```

TABLE SUB :

```
+------------+
| id_topic   |
+------------+
| 2          |
| 5          |
+------------+
```

I want to print this :

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id_topic    | topic_name  | subscribed  |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | books       | no          |
| 2           | food        | yes         |
| 3           | movies      | no          |
| 4           | weather     | no          |
| 5           | travel      | yes         |
| 6           | pets        | no          |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: please provide your question or your problem besides the information about your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [`left join`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) and a CASE statement:

```
select 
  t.*,
  case 
    when s.id_topic is null then 'no'
    else 'yes'
  end subscribed
from topics t left join sub s
on s.id_topic = t.id_topic
```